# Cross domain tracking with new analytics.js syntax?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, cross-domain

I am using Google Analytics and I am trying to set cross domain tracking for my website. I've read Google's [cross domain tracking guide](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en&utm_id=ad), but I am confused as to how to implement it properly.

The issue I am having is that the example code they give looks nothing like the tracking code I was given through my Google Analytics admin console.

My tracking code looks like this:

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'MyTrackingID', 'MyDomain');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

(My actual tracking ID and my domain have been censored out with `MyTrackingID` and `MyDomain`, respectively.)

However, the example tracking code given in the guide looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1']);
_gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript';
  ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' :
  'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
</script>
```

How do I add the `_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'A.com']);` "option" to my tracking code as instructed?

Comment: Google reference is here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain#autolink

Answer (score 3):

This code works for me. It is for Universal Analytics, not the older Google Analytics. Let's say you have two domains: source.com and destination.com and you want to track both domains:

On source.com:

```
<!-- Universal Analytics -->
<script type="text/javascript">
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

      ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXXX-X', 'source.com', {'allowLinker': true});
      ga('require', 'linker');
      ga('linker:autoLink', ['destination.com']);
      ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

On destination.com:

```
<!-- Universal Analytics -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'source.com',{'allowLinker': true});
    ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

Comment: I have a question about ClientIDs for both source and destination. Should I use the same clientID for both snippets or each website should have its own clientID ?

Comment: The client ID (UA-XXXXXXX-X) must be the same in source.com and destination.com.

Answer (score 1):

Script to add to the snippet [provided by Google](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342)

On your domain you need to add

```
ga('require', 'linker'); // Load the plugin.
// Define which domains to autoLink.
ga('linker:autoLink', ['3-party.com', '3-party-domain.com']); //add as many as you need third party sites
```

on third party domain update the existing `create` function to

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-X', {
  'allowLinker': true
});
```

Note by Google: While this feature is designed to work automatically for most websites, some pages may be scripted in ways that prevent Auto Linking from functioning properly.

Answer (score -2):

Correct implementation is following which is working perfect for myself  -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1']);
_gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript';
  ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' :
  'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
</script>
```

For setting domain, you can add -

```
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'A.com']);
```

below of

```
_gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

Comment: This is the correct implementation for the `ga.js` API/syntax, as per the examples Google gives. But this doesn't answer my question. I was asking how to to set up cross domain tracking with the new `analytics.ja` API/syntax that Google seems to want new users to use.

Comment: Ok, i understand that you want to use new analytics.js. Please note that this is currently in public beta version. You can check this link for autolinking of cross domain - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain#autolink